# Why do Kaecilius and his minions never use any relics as weapons?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

Thoughout the whole movie, Kaecilius and his minions never use any relics as weapons. They always conjure weapons instead.

Does that demonstrate that relics never get to choose zealots as their users, or they are just not user-friendly for zealots?

The only clue I have is what Mordo says in the middle of the movie:

> This is a relic.
>
> Some magic is too powerful to sustain...
>
> so we imbue objects with it...

Not sure this is relevant.

Comment: They use Sling Rings a lot

Comment: I know, but Sling Rings are not relics. Besides, they are not even weapons. Every trainee gets to use Sling Rings, but not relics unless they reach cerntain level. @DisturbedNeo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that **they don't need to**. Kaecilius and his minions are not necessarily concerned with making themselves more powerful through relics. Rather, they get their power from the Dark Dimension, which as far as we know, contains power greater than that held in relics (as they easily overcame all of the sorcerers wielding relics in Hong Kong). This is even evident in the opening scene where **they completely ignore an infinity stone** in favor of a few pages explaining how to draw power from the Dark Dimension. The Dark Dimension gives them all of the power they need, greater than that of any relic or even, to some degree, The Eye of Agamotto, as we see that Kaecilius and his followers use their powers to negate the effects of the Eye during the final battle (i.e. to prevent themselves from being subject to the reversal of time). I don't think it is ever fully explained how powerful Dormammu is, but in the comics he fights the likes of the Silver Surfer and Galactus, two EXTREMELY powerful cosmic beings. So if that gives you any idea of what the Dark Dimension is capable of, I think it is safe to say that Kaecilius and the other zealots are not in desperate need of more powerful magic.

Comment: Wow! I never read comics. Is Dormammu as powerful as Thanos?

Comment: @KinzleB Yes, definitely so.